# MySQL AES-CBC decryption key padding - what if String is too small? (no multiple of 16)

Tags: mysql, encryption, cryptography, aes, pkcs#7

I successfully encrypted Strings in MySQL using AES-128-CBC algorithm. The official documentation and tutorials helped a lot. From my understanding, MySQL uses key padding PKCS#7 in order to fill the binary data in chunks of 16 Byte-size.

**Problem: I am not able to decrypt Data using MySQL, although these Data is successfully decrypted using online decryption tools?!**

**Data:**

0x568aed71e43af834900bec738e08c4fa2637b8915fb401fd6296f19c3aeeceebc3164b967cd5445e6aafe90f416314191cb1839210b7cd2efe168911fd465dab56ccda9c82862b90f29353ab57532b49

This is a telegram that I received from a smoke detector. I can easyly decrypt it via online tools, e.g. 'online-domain-tools.com':

**AES Key:**
0xDDCCFA1971D96B759B6A20400E00A535
**iv:**
2515485001000C1A2323232323232323

**Result in online-AES-decryptor-webpage:** 0x2f2f0bfd0f070101046d3209972702fd17000082206c9225426c90278440ff2c000f13ff8250fd61000082506c01018260fd6105008360fd31e87a0082606c9b258270fd61070082706c97272f2f2f2f

I can confirm the result beeing correct, due to the prefix (2f2f) and suffix (2f2f2f2f).

I tried the same decryption in MySQL using aes-128-CBC algorithm, but the result is *NULL*?!?!

---

SET @@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-cbc';

SET @iv = 0x2515485001000C1A2323232323232323;

SET @pass = 0xDDCCFA1971D96B759B6A20400E00A535;

SET @raw = 0x568aed71e43af834900bec738e08c4fa2637b8915fb401fd6296f19c3aeeceebc3164b967cd5445e6aafe90f416314191cb1839210b7cd2efe168911fd465dab56ccda9c82862b90f29353ab57532b49;

SELECT HEX(AES_DECRYPT(@raw,@pass, @iv));

---

After a weekend of frustration my only understanding was, that if I encrypt the above data within the same procedure, the Result is as follows:

**Encryption:**
0x568aed71e43af834900bec738e08c4fa2637b8915fb401fd6296f19c3aeeceebc3164b967cd5445e6aafe90f416314191cb1839210b7cd2efe168911fd465dab56ccda9c82862b90f29353ab57532b49**ac0e75a2663f9a22b1036d03e2f9b9a6**

Heureka! The Result is different to the Result that I expected (addition of 16 Bytes, bold formatting). My suggestion is, that MySQL was unable to decrypt my initial data due to key padding? If i decrypt the longer data above, the only difference is key padding bytes at the end of the original data:

**Decrypted:**

0x2f2f0bfd0f070101046d3209972702fd17000082206c9225426c90278440ff2c000f13ff8250fd61000082506c01018260fd6105008360fd31e87a0082606c9b258270fd61070082706c97272f2f2f2f**10101010101010101010**

The bold bytes at the end is key padding data, from my understanding.

**Other decryption result in MySQL (no key padding?!):**

---

SET @@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-cbc';

SET @iv = 0x2515485001000C1A2323232323232323;

SET @pass = 0xDDCCFA1971D96B759B6A20400E00A535;

SET @raw = 0x568aed71e43af834900bec738e08c4fa2637b8915fb401fd6296f19c3aeeceebc3164b967cd5445e6aafe90f416314191cb1839210b7cd2efe168911fd465dab56ccda9c82862b90f29353ab57532b49ac0e75a2663f9a22b1036d03e2f9b9a6;

SELECT HEX(AES_DECRYPT(@raw,@pass, @iv));

---

**Is there a way to 'add' the *missing* bytes to **encrypted data**, in order to enable MySQL to decrypt it?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post the SQL used for each of the above examples.

Comment: I added the code. I hope my question is not too much confusing now :-)

Comment: This is possible, but it's probably too cumbersome to be helpful (s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))): XOR the last ciphertext block 0x56cc...2b49 with the padding block 0x1010...1010. Encrypt the result with AES in ECB mode without padding with the key 0xddcc...a535. This results in the searched last ciphertext block: ac0e...b9a6. If the last step is performed with padding, only the first 16 bytes may be used.

Comment: @Topaco - I'm trying to test your suggestion.  1) Would "...XOR the last ciphertext block ...with the padding block" just return the last ciphertext block in this case? 2) Also, regarding "...Encrypt the result with AES in ECB mode ..."  why use ECB mode for this step? Just trying to understand why I'm not getting the result `ac0e...b9a6`

Comment: @SOS - The logic is most easily understood with the flowchart of the [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)). For encryption, the AES primitive must be applied, which encrypts a single block. Alternatively, AES can be used in ECB Mode without padding (with padding, the 2nd block must be removed).

Comment: @SOS - S. here for an online calculation: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex('Auto')XOR(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'10101010101010101010101010101010'%7D,'Standard',false)AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'ddccfa1971d96b759b6a20400e00a535'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'ECB','Raw','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)Drop_bytes(32,32,false)&input=NTZjY2RhOWM4Mjg2MmI5MGYyOTM1M2FiNTc1MzJiNDk

Comment: @Topaco - Now that site is awesome. Really helps illustrate the descriptions from wiki. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Martrix - I could be wrong, but .. if I'm understanding the description above correctly, I don't think it could be done with MySQL alone because AFAIK it doesn't support ECB mode.

Comment: @SOS - yes that is my understanding, as well. I use the following 'workaround' at the moment: I cut the Input Data from 160 characters to 128 characters. The data is decryptable but I loose a few bytes of information, unfortunately.

Comment: No way you can change the sender encryption settings, or maybe use an external tool to construct the correct value for MySQL?

Comment: @SOS unfortunately, the receiver-hardware and -software both are proprietary. I cannot change the output data of the tool. But fortunately, the bytes I loose are less important :-)

Comment: The old black box of OPS (Other People's Software ;-). Ah well, glad you got something working... and thanks for the interesting question :)